# Associating ViewModels with Fragments in MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We have a couple of Fragments that we use as common controls:

1. MyCommonHeaderA
2. MyCommonHeaderB

In our common `View` class we call `base.OnCreate(bundle)` and once that has returned we fish out the fragment instances and set their ViewModels

```
var commonHeaderAFragment = (MyCommonHeaderA)this.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.header1banner);
if (commonHeaderAFragment != null)
{
    commonHeaderAFragment.ViewModel = this.ViewModel;
}

var commonHeaderBFragment = (MyCommonHeaderB)this.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.header2banner);
if (commonHeaderBFragment != null)
{
    commonHeaderBFragment.ViewModel = this.ViewModel;
}
```

Until recently this has been working with no problem. Recently we have upgraded Xamarin and MVVMCross.

Now whenever we rotate the device OnCreate is called and the execution path ends up in `MvxFragmentExtensions.OnCreate` where it tries to lookup a type for the Fragment using `FindAssociatedViewModelTypeOrNull`. There is no associated ViewModel type for the Fragment. We never needed to, should we have associated a type?

I did try MvxViewForAttribute and concrete typed ViewModel property but neither of those worked as they wanted to create new VM instances.

I have a solution which is that in the base OnCreate, if we have a bundle try and find the Fragments and set their `ViewModel` property *before* `base.onCreate` and when there is no bundle we set the `ViewModel` property after OnCreate. It is clunky but works. I just wanted to check if we should have been setting up our Fragments differently so that we would not have hit this issue

Answer (score 0):

There is an example available that uses the MvxCachingFragmentActivity: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

In there you don't need to worry about those kind of problems anymore.

Comment: the link you provided returns a 404